# Python Flask-Restful POST not taking JSON arguments

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am very new to Flask (& Flask-Restful).

My problem : `json` arguments for a `POST` is getting set to `NONE` (not working).

I am able to take arguments from the `form-data`, using `POSTMAN` plugin for chrome. But, when i switch to `raw` (& feed a `json`), it fails to read the json & assigns a `NONE` to all my arguments.

I have read some related stackoverflow posts related to this : [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273671/flask-restful-post-json-fails), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982151/flask-with-flask-restful-not-parsing-json-payloads), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384526/how-to-parse-the-post-argument-to-a-rest-service) ... none of these helped me.

I am using `python-2.6`, `Flask-Restful-0.3.3`, `Flask-0.10.1`, `Chrome`, `POSTMAN` on Oracle Linux 6.5.

**Python code** `app.py` :

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
parser.add_argument('password', type=str)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        un = str(args['username'])
        pw = str(args['password'])
        return jsonify(u=un, p=pw)

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/testing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5444 ,debug=True)
```

**Testing this** using `POSTMAN` :

- Using `form-data` : works perfectly !
- Using `raw` -> `json` : *causes this issue*

**Things tried #1** :

Add `json` parameter to my `add_argument()` method in `app.py`

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('username', type=str, location='json') # added json
parser.add_argument('password', type=str, location='json') # added json
```

`Input` : { "username": "hello", "password": "world" }

`Output` : { "p": "None", "u": "None" }

**Things tried #2** :

Change type to `unicode` in `add_argument()` method in `app.py`

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('username', type=unicode, location='json') # change type to unicode
parser.add_argument('password', type=unicode, location='json') # change type to unicode
```

`Input` : { "username": "hello", "password": "world" }

`Output` : { "p": "None", "u": "None" }

---

**PS :** 
I will keep updating my question, with every failed attempt. 
Please let me know if you need any more info to make this question more clear.

Comment: Looks to me like you're missing a call to `parser.parse_args()`. You should have `args = parser.parse_args()` before you can access the `args`

Comment: @junnytony - its a typo from my side, i forgot to copy that line. Editing the question right away!

Comment: Try `unicode` instead of `str` for the arguments types

Comment: @Sir_FZ `unicode` has the same issue, retains `None`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Request.json](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.json,) and the new [Request.get_json](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.get_json), you should have the mimetype on your POST request set to `application/json`. This is the only way flask will automatically parse your JSON data into the `Request.json` property which (I believe) is what Flask-Restful depends on to retrieve JSON data.

NOTE: The newer `get_json` function has an option to force the parsing of POST data as JSON irrespective of the mimetype

Answer (score 37):

junnytony's answer gave me a hint, and I went ahead with this approach. `get_json` seems to have done the trick.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

#parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
#parser.add_argument('username', type=unicode, location='json')
#parser.add_argument('password', type=unicode, location='json')

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def post(self):
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        un = json_data['username']
        pw = json_data['password']
        #args = parser.parse_args()
        #un = str(args['username'])
        #pw = str(args['password'])
        return jsonify(u=un, p=pw)

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/testing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5444 ,debug=True)
```

Comment: Nice :). but I think your code would be even more awesome if you changed the mimetype for your post to be 'application/json'. I'm guessing you're using AJAX for your post. With something like jQuery you can easily add the appropriate mimetype for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice

Comment: Thanks for providing your final code, I have a similar use case.

Comment: HI, I am also facing the same issue.As per your suggestion I done but still getting bad request error

Comment: what your exact issue @KCN?

Comment: As per your suggestion I followed like json_dat = request.get_json(force=True)
  fname = json_dat["firstname"]
  lname = json_dat["lastname"]  but while executing this url from rest client getting 400 bad request error

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar issue and here is a solution that works for me. let's say your application looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# Define parser and request args
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('last_name', type=str)
parser.add_argument('first_name', type=str)
# not the type=dict
parser.add_argument('personal_data', type=dict)


class Item(Resource):

    def post(self):

        args = parser.parse_args()

        ln = args['last_name']
        fn = args['first_name']
        # we can also easily parse nested structures
        age = args['personal_data']['age']
        nn = args['personal_data']['nicknames']

        return jsonify(fn=fn, ln=ln, age=age, nn=nn)


api.add_resource(Item, '/item')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, you can easily create some JSON data:

```
import json

d = {'last_name': 'smith', 'first_name': 'john', 'personal_data': {'age': 18, 'height': 180, 'nicknames': ['johnny', 'grandmaster']}}

print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))

{
    "last_name": "smith",
    "first_name": "john",
    "personal_data": {
        "age": 18,
        "height": 180,
        "nicknames": [
            "johnny",
            "grandmaster"
        ]
    }
}

json.dumps(d)
'{"last_name": "smith", "first_name": "john", "personal_data": {"age": 18, "height": 180, "nicknames": ["johnny", "grandmaster"]}}'
```

and call the application:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/item -d '{"last_name": "smith", "first_name": "john", "personal_data": {"age": 18, "height": 180, "nicknames": ["johnny", "grandmaster"]}}'
```

This will crash with the error (I shortened the traceback):

> age = args['personal_data']['age']
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

the reason is that the header is not specified. If we add the

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

and then call

```
curl http://localhost:5000/item -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"last_name": "smith", "first_name": "john", "personal_data": {"age": 18, "height": 180, "nicknames": ["johnny", "grandmaster"]}}'
```

The output looks as expected:

```
{
  "age": 18, 
  "fn": "john", 
  "ln": "smith", 
  "nn": [
    "johnny", 
    "grandmaster"
  ]
}
```

The function can be also further simplified to:

```
class Item(Resource):

    def post(self):

        json_data = request.get_json()
        # create your response below
```

as [shown above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493521/1534017).

Answer (score 6):

After forcing the request to parse json, it worked with me.
Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
parser.add_argument('password', type=str)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def post(self):
        request.get_json(force=True)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        un = str(args['username'])
        pw = str(args['password'])
        return jsonify(u=un, p=pw)

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/testing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5444 ,debug=True)
```