# How to force a flask-restful app to interpret the post body as json regardsless of the request's mime-type

Tags: python, json, rest, flask

I have a python  `flask-restful` app which receives json in the post body. Here the two minimal files `app.py` and `info.py`:

**The application module `app.py`:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

flaskApp = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(flaskApp)

from endpoints.info import Info

api.add_resource(Infp, '/v1/info')
```

**The endpoint module `info.py` (in subfolder `endpoints`):**

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse

myParser = reqparse.RequestParser()
reqparse.RequestParser.
myParser.add_argument('argA', location='json')
myParser.add_argument('argB', location='json')


class Info(Resource):

    def post(self):
        args = myParser.parse_args()
        return args
```

This app works correct when I send a request as mime type `application/json`:

```
curl  -s "http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/info" -d '{"locality":"Barton"}' -H Content-Type:application/json
```

returns as expected:

```
{
    "locality": "Barton"
}
```

However *the client will send the requests as the normal url-encoded mimetype*. When I just do

```
curl  -s "http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/info" -d '{"locality":"Barton"}'
```

the app returns `{}` So it did not interpret the body as intended.

***How can I force the app to interpret the post body as json regardsless of the request's mime-type?***

I know about [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491841/python-flask-restful-post-not-taking-json-arguments); it suggests using`Request.get_json`. But how can I access this method in the `Resource` class `Info` to feed it into `myParser`?

Comment: One could give the argument, that such a request would be invalid.

Comment: You can use `request.get_json(force=True)`, refer to the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.get_json) for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the flask-restful docs](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/api.html#reqparse.Argument), the `location` keyword argument of `add_argument` indicates a property of `flask.Request` from which to pull the argument.

According to [the Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.json), the `json` property will be empty if the mimetype of the request is not `application/json`.

But if you use `Request.get_json(force=True)` directly, you don't need the parser. You can just access the value:

```
from flask import request
class Info(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        return data['locality']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it out on Monday. :-)

Comment: @halloleo Let us know whether the `type` argument really does accept arbitrary casting functions! The documentation is pretty terse on that point.

Comment: Yep, this works. Thanks a million.:-) Obviously I have to implement the filtering, done previously by `RequestParser` myself after receiving the arguments in `data`.

Comment: @halloleo Did you try passing `location='data'` and `type=lambda x:json.loads(x)` to `add_argument`?

Comment: No, no, I went for the `get_json` solution. When I try the RequestParser solution via `add_argument(p, location='data', type=lambda x:json.loads(x))` I get: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'".

Comment: @halloleo That makes sense; the `type` function casts the "got" value, not the data structure to "get" it from. Rats.