# Flask rest plus Parser does not seem to work with post

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have written below code endpoint to post data received from front end, I have implemented the same way for get and it works but does not work for post

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("update", type=bool, help="Update the data set") 
parser.add_argument(
"set_name", type=str, help="Name of the set you want to add

@api.route("/add_set")
 class AddNewSet(Resource): 
@api.doc(parser=parser) 
def post(self):
     """ endpoint that handles request for deploying services 
         :return: (int) deployed service id from database. 
     """

          print "Hello hellooo"
          args = parser.parse_args() 
          print "doink"
```

throws error:

{ "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: No JSON object could be decoded"
 }

And the text "doink" does not get printed  so I gave doubt `parser.parse_args()` is not working as expected I believe or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What are you posting? What happens when you remove `@api.doc(parser=parser) `?

Comment: if I remove `@api.doc(parser=parser)` then arguments I expect to fetch dont show up in swagger documentaiton

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz you must set [location](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html#argument-locations) to arguments. Parser doesn't know where is arguments(`form`, `json` or `headers` etc.)

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382536/1534017) which - I think - solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the RequestParser looks for args from request.json and request.values

Plz see: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html#argument-locations

As for your code, I haven't try your way to define args for post, I do this way

```py
@api.expect(api.model(
  'ModelName', dict(
    arg1 = fields.String(required=True),
    arg2 = fields.Integer,
  )
))
def post(self):
  return {'result': 'success'}
```

I also recommend to give a clear return clause, even `return None`.